# Does ABPerson in iOS have kABModificationDateProperty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Does ABPerson in iOS have kABModificationDateProperty? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it does have [kABPersonModificationDateProperty](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kABPersonModificationDateProperty).